# Sass nav nesting not working

Tags: html, sass, nav, nested

Using HTML5 `nav` element and nesting SASS properties. None of the properties are being applied to the html. Not sure where the issue is.

Here is my sass:

```
nav{height:4em;width:100%;position:relative;padding:10px;z-index:1000;
  ul{list-style:none;}
  li{display:inline;font-size:130%;"
   a{color:#333;text-decoration:none; padding:5px;
    &:hover{border-bottom:#f8a593 2px solid;}
    &:active{border-bottom:#fd5d39 2px solid;}
}
```

And here is my html:

```
  <nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a class="active-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
       <li><a href="#.html">Le Me</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it because on that line:

```
li{display:inline;font-size:130%;"
```

the latest character should be *}*, not *"*. Once I changed it, your code is compiled to:

```
nav {
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1000; }
  nav ul {
    list-style: none; }
  nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 130%; }
  nav li a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px; }
  nav:hover {
    border-bottom: #f8a593 2px solid; }
  nav:active {
    border-bottom: #fd5d39 2px solid; }
```

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Not exactly - I believe that converts it back to CSS syntax.

Comment: But your SASS code as it is right now it's not compileable. Just paste it here http://sass-lang.com/try.html and you will see where the mistake is.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you pasted in your previous comment was actually SCSS?

Comment: Finally figured out the issue - I was linking to the sass stylesheet in my html instead of the compiled/css file. Fixed all the issues. Thanks for the help!